# Fixed position div background issue

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a website with a fixed position div for the menu so that it is always at the top of the screen when I scroll down the page. This was working fine until recently when I noticed it looses its background and sometimes gets stuck in random places on the page. I have searched for solutions but with no luck.
Any help or suggestions is much appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you think you could post some code? Even better, how about a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that shows the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does your code look similar to this?

http://jsfiddle.net/vJhp4/1/

this show the menu fixed at the top of the body tag while scrolling.

```
#menu {
    position:fixed;
    left:50%;
    top:0;
    height:20px;
    width:50px;
    background-color:black;
    color:#FFF;
    padding-top:2px;
    text-align:center;
}
```